# Linux permissions with svn and Syncro

Tags: svn

I am using a GUI (Syncro for MAC) and SSh. I set the username to "svn" but I am using MY public key to connect. Can someone explain how this would work? I never have to give it my server username.
and all commits are registered to user svn
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely put your public key into the `~svn/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the SVN server and configured Syncro to connect to `svn@svnserver.com`. SSH will then try the private keys it finds in your own `~/.ssh/` directory to see if one fits. If it fits, you are logged in as user `svn`. That's all.